# Filtering polygons that intersect polyline dataset using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am trying to filter a polygon dataset that intersects with a polyline dataset.  I want all polygons that touch the polyline to be filtered out into a new shapefile.  I can't seem to make the intersect tool to work to do this as it won't allow polygon output with a polyline input.  I am working with ArcMap 10.6.

How do I make this dataset?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do what you want is to use the Select by Location feature.

In the Selection tab along the top of ArcMap, click on the Select by Location.

Select the polygon feature from the Target layer, and the polyline feature in the Source Layer underneath.

Make sure the selection method is intersect the source feature layer.

The polygon features that intersect the polyline will become highlighted on the map. You can then right click on the polygon in the Table of Contents of the map, click on Data, and then click on Export Data. This will allow you to export it as a shapefile or feature class.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I appreciate the response. However, when I try this it does not highlight any polygons on the map.  Any guidance on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: First off, are you sure they intersect? Is the data projected properly? Are any of the records in blue you try using the select by location and then open the attribute table for the polygon?

Comment: One of my layers happened to be corrupt so I reset everything and it seems to be working great now.  Thanks again Adam, really appreciated!